# How to perform a fallback to a previous version of a python package delivered on artifactory without customers noticing

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

## Context

I am developing a Python package that I want to continuously deliver to artifactory. I also have a certain number of machines (my customers) with an automatized scheduled job using this package, as follows:

```
pip install --upgrade foo # Make sure to use the latest version delivered to artifactory
foo do_something          # Then use the package
```

## Problem/Question

Let's say I discover that the latest version I delivered to artifactory contains a bug.
**Is there a way to perform a fallback seamlessly, i.e without having to intervene on the machines nor on the scheduled jobs to tell them which version of the package to use?**

## Initial idea of a solution

I was thinking of working with a 'latest'-tag-solution:

1. At each new release, I would tag the new artifact as the latest, and untag the previous one.
2. Instead of doing a pip upgrade, I would do a pip install targetting the latest tag
3. When I need to do a fallback to a previous version, I would simply tag the version to which I want to fallback as latest.
4. Once the bug fixed, I would release again my package as a new minor version and tag it as latest.

My customer would automatically use the latest working version without noticing that it has changed.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use pip directly to target a specific version of a package based on a custom property like "latest" in JFrog Artifactory.

Comment: What counts for you as "without customers noticing". If you are willing to replace the current version with a lower one, why not make the bugfix a new minor version instead?

Comment: @FlyingTeller This is indeed what I do. But while I am fixing the bug, I want to fallback to a previous version that I would tag to latest, so that they don't even notice the fallback. This is what I meant by "without customers noticing".

Comment: I do not know the details, but what I would probably look into if I were in your situation is a solution where the problematic releases are yanked from the index server on one hand, and on the other hand check different combinations of _pip_ options such as [`--ignore-installed`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-I), [`--force-reinstall`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-force-reinstall), [`--upgrade-strategy`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-upgrade-strategy) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not think of one true blessed way to do this, but I can think of some ways you can probably get close enough (not knowing what the truth of the requirements of the project)...

One way could be to let *pip* install from a *git branch*. For example you could make it so that *pip* installs from a `stable` branch, which you you would be free to move to any commit you want at any time.

Another possible solution I can think of, is to use some kind of dummy *pip*-installable package distributed on your package index server that would serve as some kind of [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) pointing to the true package. In this scenario the indirection package would contain no code but would declare one and only one **pinned** dependency on the true package. It could be that the true package follows semantic versioning, but I would recommend the indirection package to follow some kind of calendar-based versioning. You would be free to upload a new version of the indirection package at any time. For example `bar 2023.01.01` (the indirection package) currently depends on `foo==3.2.1` (the true package). A bug is discovered in `foo 3.2.1` and you decide customers should fall back on `foo 3.2.0` until you can fix the bug, in this case you could immediately distribute `bar 2023.06.05` that depends on `foo==3.2.0`, and `pip install --upgrade bar && foo do_something` will do what you expect. One month later when `foo 3.2.2` is ready with the bug fix, you could publish `bar 2023.07.05` that depends on `foo==3.2.2`.

Having a pinned dependency would give full control, but it is most likely not necessary. The indirection package could also declare a dependency such as `foo >=3.2.0, !=3.2.1`, so that the `3.2.2` bugfix release would be automatically included.